# MediaWiki 1.19: How to load JavaScript in head?

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, modernizr

I want to use Modernizr for my MediaWiki skin, but it appears that ResourceLoader only loads scripts at the bottom of the `<body>`. Is there a way for me to load it in the `<head>`?

Based on @Bergi's answer below, I created an extension with the 'top' position to get it to load in the head:

**extensions/Modernizr/Modernizr.php**

```
<?php

$wgResourceModules['ext.Modernizr.foo'] = array(
    'scripts' => 'modules/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js',
    'remoteExtPath' => 'Modernizr',
    'position' => 'top'
);
```

The modernizr-2.6.2.min.js file is in the **extensions/Modernizr/modules/** folder.

And load it as follows:
**LocalSettings.php**

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/Modernizr/Modernizr.php" );
```

In the `execute()` function in my skin file:

```
global $wgOut;
$wgOut->addModules('ext.Modernizr.foo');
```

Is this the wrong place to call `$wgOut->addModules()`?

Modernizr is still not being loaded or run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify a [`position` parameter for scripts](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Migration_guide_for_extension_developers#Inline_JavaScript) in the [`$wgResourceModules`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgResourceModules) definition. Set it to `top` for modernizr and then load it via [`$wgOut->addModules`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader#Server-side).

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it working. I've added details about the changes I made in my question.

Comment: Hm, I'm not that experienced with the PHP development, but I guess you will need to add the [`localBasePath`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader#Registering) to the definition